# How can I create a random walk animation with animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

The idea is to have a bunch of objects that are animated given a random vector each 20 frames. Something like this video:

https://vimeo.com/75135375

The problem that I´ve found with Animation Nodes is how to somehow store the previous positions of the objects that sometimes could be 20 frames away. For the first animation I can use the ID key, but as long as the animation continues I can keep it consistent.

Comment: [For the first animation I can use the ID key, but as long as the animation continues I can keep it consistent]   .   [consistent], What does that sentence mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no very efficient way to do this.

If you only have a few objects this solution might work for you:

[image]

Essentially you generate the whole path for each object in each frame.

Comment: I see. This is one of the few weak points on AN.  How to make objects aware of their previous states.